# Number of business days for each month

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I habe a data frame with dates from 2012 - 2021. The dates are only business dates. So no weekends.
I need a column with the number for each business date for every month.

Comment: check the package bizdays.

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(clock)

tibble(date = date_seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), by = duration_days(1), total_size = 365)) |>
  mutate(
    wkday = date_weekday_factor(date),
    date = as_year_month_day(date),
    month = calendar_group(date, "month")
  ) |> 
  filter(!wkday %in% c("Sat", "Sun")) |> 
  group_by(month) |> 
  mutate(bus_day = row_number())
#> # A tibble: 260 × 4
#> # Groups:   month [12]
#>    date       wkday month        bus_day
#>    <ymd<day>> <ord> <ymd<month>>   <int>
#>  1 2022-01-03 Mon   2022-01            1
#>  2 2022-01-04 Tue   2022-01            2
#>  3 2022-01-05 Wed   2022-01            3
#>  4 2022-01-06 Thu   2022-01            4
#>  5 2022-01-07 Fri   2022-01            5
#>  6 2022-01-10 Mon   2022-01            6
#>  7 2022-01-11 Tue   2022-01            7
#>  8 2022-01-12 Wed   2022-01            8
#>  9 2022-01-13 Thu   2022-01            9
#> 10 2022-01-14 Fri   2022-01           10
#> # … with 250 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Great answer @Carl! Thanks for using clock. I wanted to follow up and show that you can also do this nicely with almanac + clock too, which I designed for this exact use case. almanac is nice because you can also exclude holidays if you'd like to. I can't post an answer because this question is closed, so here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/DavisVaughan/e09146b76cf2a5a0706b1cbf9bc2800b

Answer (score 0):

According to how you describe your question, you just need the number of the day in the week as you mention that your data does not include anything else than working days.

You can use the library lubridate for example

```
lubridate::wday("2022-04-24", week_start = 1L) # sunday will be 7
# [1] 7

lubridate::wday("2022-04-24") # sunday will be 1
# [1] 1
```